# Increment Sheet Number in Existing Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to increase the sheet number within the below formula Where the sheet name is `'Week 1 Shifts'` This formula is all correct but I want to drag to the next column up to Week 5 Shifts.

I have read the other answers on this site and although I can find the Indirect function and understand how it works (I think) I cannot recreate it in my formula as it stands.

Existing formula in Cell E26
=`'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$20+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$33+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$46+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$59+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$72+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$85+'Week 1 Shifts'!$AC$98`

What I want the formula in Cell E28 to look like, E30 will be Week 3, and so on
=`'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$20+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$33+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$46+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$59+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$72+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$85+'Week 2 Shifts'!$AC$98`

I expect the outcome to be 5 cells with 5 formulas with each week being the same in each cell but increasing across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, e.g.,

`=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()-1&"!A1")`

All you need to do is find a way to count the number of of the sheet you are trying to access that will automatically change across rows. In this case we use `ROW()-` (some amount of rows); some other reference or calculation might work better depending on the specifics of your sheet. Your basic formula is  `=INDIRECT("string"&`{calculation or reference to number}`&"remainder of string")`; adjust as needed